# make Android kernel - modules prepare

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

For some context, I'm trying to build and use the [LiME forensics tool](http://code.google.com/p/lime-forensics/). Essentially, this entails building a kernel module, to extract the contents of RAM without touching user-space. Following the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/lime-forensics/downloads/list) on their page, I've set up the environment, downloaded the kernel source, and pulled the config file off the phone.

Now, they tell me to:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CC_PATH/arm-eabi- modules_prepare
```

My first question is: what is modules_prepare, and why am I making it? But specifically, when I run that, I get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `modules_prepare'.  Stop.
```

This is what I would expect, since there is in fact no mention of modules_prepare anywhere to be found. So why are they telling me to make it?

Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linux-Kernel-Documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) may help you understanding `modules_prepare`

Comment: I think I get the premise of modules_prepare; it makes sure that everything necessary is present for cross-linking? What I can't figure out is why I'm told to do it if there's no rule for it in the Makefile. My assumption was that the authors knew something about make, and modules_prepare, that I don't - but is it possible that I'm just executing it improperly?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CC_PATH/arm-eabi- modules_prepare

Use

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CC_PATH/arm-eabi- modules

And if you get

> "The present kernel configuration has modules disabled.Type 'make config' and enable loadable module support.Then build a kernel with module support enabled
>       make: *** [modules] Error 1"

Then you have to modify the .config by adding

> CONFIG_MODULES=y
>       CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y

This blog http://sgros-students.blogspot.ca/2014/04/lime.html covers extensively LiME deployment and gives plenty of details regarding common errors including this one.